# Error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I updated all my dependencies to use hooks in React Native. They are:

```
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "^0.59.5",
"react-navigation": "^3.9.0"
```

Before updating dependencies, the development server worked well, but after updating to newest versions it shows errors:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes` from `C:\Koolpeace\apps\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\createAnimatedComponent.js`: Module `react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes` does not exist in the Haste module map
INFO
21:13
This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
INFO
21:13
To resolve try the following:
INFO
21:13
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
INFO
21:13
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
INFO
21:13
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
INFO
21:13
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

I tried everything on the internet. I emptied caches. I emptied all kinds of caches including

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

None of them worked for me. I deleted node_modules and reinstalled everything several times. It was the same. I wrote only simple things and the problem must be something with crash within dependencies. But I have no idea where it got wrong. I also tried downgraded. Till to

```
"react": "^16.8",
"react-native": "^0.59"
```

The minimum versions that support hooks. It did not work either.

I tried to code on Expo Snack. The snack raises type error: undefined is not a function. near) useEffect...

I guess the expo snack platform uses outdated React and React Native.

Now, what can I do? How can run the development server and continue to debug using QR code and my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks aren't still supported in Expo. There's a feature request about this, but it's still in progress: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-react-1680-aka-hooks

Comment: Oh... that was why!! I already spent half a day but you saved my another day haha I couldn't find whether Expo supports hooks although I Googled it. Thank you for letting me know about it! I will need to use classes for quite a while then.